# Proper way to pool client channels in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I'm getting a java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException in the following code because I'm trying to write to a channel that is not yet open.

Essentially what I have is a channel pool in which I grab a channel to write to if one is free, and I create a new channel if one is not available. My problem is that when I create a new channel, the channel is not ready for writing when I call connect, and I don't want to wait for the connection to open before returning because I don't want to block the thread. What's the best way to do this? Also, is my logic for retrieving/returning channels valid? See code below.

I have a simple connection pool like the following:

```
private static class ChannelPool {
    private final ClientBootstrap cb;
    private Set<Channel> activeChannels = new HashSet<Channel>();
    private Deque<Channel> freeChannels = new ArrayDeque<Channel>();
    public ChannelPool() {
        ChannelFactory clientFactory =
                new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        cb = new ClientBootstrap(clientFactory);
        cb.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
                return Channels.pipeline(
                        new HttpRequestEncoder(),
                        new HttpResponseDecoder(),
                        new ResponseHandler());
            }
        });
    }

    private Channel newChannel() {
        ChannelFuture cf;
        synchronized (cb) {
            cf = cb.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 18080));
        }
        final Channel ret = cf.getChannel();
        ret.getCloseFuture().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("channel closed?");
                synchronized (activeChannels) {
                    activeChannels.remove(ret);
                }
            }
        });
        synchronized (activeChannels) {
            activeChannels.add(ret);
        }
        System.out.println("returning new channel");
        return ret;
    }

    public Channel getFreeChannel() {
        synchronized (freeChannels) {
            while (!freeChannels.isEmpty()) {
                Channel ch = freeChannels.pollFirst();
                if (ch.isOpen()) {
                    return ch;
                }
            }
        }
        return newChannel();
    }

    public void returnChannel(Channel ch) {
        synchronized (freeChannels) {
            freeChannels.addLast(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use this inside a handler as follows:

```
private static class RequestHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {
        final HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
        Channel proxyChannel = pool.getFreeChannel();
        proxyToClient.put(proxyChannel, e.getChannel());
        proxyChannel.write(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748424/how-to-create-channel-pool-in-netty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the new channel to `activeChannels` immediately after `bootstrap.connect(..)`, you have to add a listener to the `ChannelFuture` which was returned by `bootstrap.connect(..)`, and add the channel to `activeChannels` in the added listener.  That way, `getFreeChannel()` will never get the channel that is not connected yet.

Because it is likely that `activeChannels` is empty even if you called `newChannel()` (`newChannel()` will return even before connection is established), you have to decide what to do in such a case.  If I were you, I would change the return type of `getFreeChannel()` from `Channel` to `ChannelFuture` so that the caller gets notified when the free channel is ready.

Comment: I don't suppose you have any ideas why I'm still getting 'connection reset by peer' (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818767/what-events-do-i-need-to-listen-to-in-order-to-reuse-a-client-connection-in-nett).