# What events do I need to listen to in order to reuse a client connection in Netty (getting "Connection reset by peer")?

Tags: java, netty

I'm getting `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` when I try to reuse a client connection in Netty (this does not happen if I send one request, but happens every time if I send two requests, even from a single thread). My current approach involves the following implementing a simple ChannelPool whose code is below. Note that the key method obtains a free channel from the `freeChannels` member or creates a new channel if none are available. The method `returnChannel()` is the method responsible for freeing up a channel when we are done with the request. It is called inside the pipeline after we process the response (see `messageReceived()` method of `ResponseHandler` in the code below). Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong, and why I'm getting an exception?

Channel pool code (note use of `freeChannels.pollFirst()` to get a free channel that has been returned via a call to `returnChannel()`):

```
public class ChannelPool {

private final ClientBootstrap cb;
private Deque<Channel> freeChannels = new ArrayDeque<Channel>();
private static Map<Channel, Channel> proxyToClient = new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, Channel>();

public ChannelPool(InetSocketAddress address, ChannelPipelineFactory pipelineFactory) {
    ChannelFactory clientFactory =
            new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    cb = new ClientBootstrap(clientFactory);
    cb.setPipelineFactory(pipelineFactory);
}

private void writeToNewChannel(final Object writable, Channel clientChannel) {
    ChannelFuture cf;
    synchronized (cb) {
        cf = cb.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 18080));
    }
    final Channel ch = cf.getChannel();
    proxyToClient.put(ch, clientChannel);
    cf.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture arg0) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("channel open, writing: " + ch);
            ch.write(writable);
        }
    });
}

public void executeWrite(Object writable, Channel clientChannel) {
    synchronized (freeChannels) {
        while (!freeChannels.isEmpty()) {
            Channel ch = freeChannels.pollFirst();
            System.out.println("trying to reuse channel: " + ch + " " + ch.isOpen());
            if (ch.isOpen()) {
                proxyToClient.put(ch, clientChannel);
                ch.write(writable).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture cf) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("write from reused channel complete, success? " + cf.isSuccess());
                    }
                });
                // EDIT: I needed a return here
            }
        }
    }
    writeToNewChannel(writable, clientChannel);
}

public void returnChannel(Channel ch) {
    synchronized (freeChannels) {
        freeChannels.addLast(ch);
    }
}

public Channel getClientChannel(Channel proxyChannel) {
    return proxyToClient.get(proxyChannel);
}
}
```

Netty pipeline code (Note that `RequestHandler` calls `executeWrite()` which uses either a new or an old channel, and `ResponseHandler` calls `returnChannel()` after the response is received and the content is set in the response to the client):

```
public class NettyExample {

private static ChannelPool pool;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    pool = new ChannelPool(
            new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 18080),
            new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
                public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
                    return Channels.pipeline(
                            new HttpRequestEncoder(),
                            new HttpResponseDecoder(),
                            new ResponseHandler());
                }
            });
    ChannelFactory factory =
            new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                    Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    ServerBootstrap sb = new ServerBootstrap(factory);

    sb.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() {
            return Channels.pipeline(
                    new HttpRequestDecoder(),
                    new HttpResponseEncoder(),
                    new RequestHandler());
        }
    });

    sb.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
    sb.setOption("child.keepAlive", true);

    sb.bind(new InetSocketAddress(2080));
}

private static class ResponseHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {
        final HttpResponse proxyResponse = (HttpResponse) e.getMessage();
        final Channel proxyChannel = e.getChannel();
        Channel clientChannel = pool.getClientChannel(proxyChannel);
        HttpResponse clientResponse = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
        clientResponse.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        HttpHeaders.setContentLength(clientResponse, proxyResponse.getContent().readableBytes());
        clientResponse.setContent(proxyResponse.getContent());
        pool.returnChannel(proxyChannel);
        clientChannel.write(clientResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        ch.close();
    }
}

private static class RequestHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {
        final HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
        pool.executeWrite(request, e.getChannel());
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        Channel ch = e.getChannel();
        ch.close();
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: To give more detail, I've written a trace of what's happening on the proxy connection. Note that the following involves two serial requests performed by a synchronous apache commons client. The first request uses a new channel and completes fine, and the second request attempts to reuse the same channel, which is open and writable, but inexplicably fails (I've not been able to intercept any problem other than noticing the exception thrown from the worker thread). Evidently, the second request completes successfully when a retry is made. Many seconds after both requests complete, both connections finally close (i.e., even if the connection were closed by the peer, this is not reflected by any event I've intercepted):

```
channel open: [id: 0x6e6fbedf]
channel connect requested: [id: 0x6e6fbedf]
channel open, writing: [id: 0x6e6fbedf, /127.0.0.1:47031 => localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]
channel connected: [id: 0x6e6fbedf, /127.0.0.1:47031 => localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]
trying to reuse channel: [id: 0x6e6fbedf, /127.0.0.1:47031 => localhost/127.0.0.1:18080] true
channel open: [id: 0x3999abd1]
channel connect requested: [id: 0x3999abd1]
channel open, writing: [id: 0x3999abd1, /127.0.0.1:47032 => localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]
channel connected: [id: 0x3999abd1, /127.0.0.1:47032 => localhost/127.0.0.1:18080]
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:186)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:359)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:63)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:373)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:247)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, figured this out. There were two issues causing a connection reset. First, I was not calling `releaseConnection()` from the apache commons `HttpClient` that was sending requests to the proxy (see the [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844657/keep-client-from-closing-connection-to-a-netty-server-is-there-something-i-need)). Second, `executeWrite` was twice issuing the same call to the proxied server in the case the connection was reused. I needed to  return after the first write rather than continuing with the while loop. The result of this double proxy call was that I was issuing duplicate responses to the original client, mangling the connection with the client.