# How to create channel pool in netty?

Tags: java, netty

I am creating channel using this sample code:

```
 EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group(group)
             .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
             .handler(new ClientInitializer());

            // Start the connection attempt.
            Channel ch = b.connect(host, port).sync().channel();
```

So here my getting a channel(channel future) but my application throughput will be very high so i think that one channel will not be sufficient, so please let me know that how do i create channel pool.

I am using netty 4.0

Comment: here's an example for a channel pool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799820/proper-way-to-pool-client-channels-in-netty

Comment: Netty 4.0.28 now has support for a channel pool. See http://netty.io/news/2015/05/07/4-0-28-Final.html

Comment: Channel pool is working fine for me. The only issue which i am facing is that when server replies to client i am not able to get that in my client handler (extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> ) channelRead0 method. Any hint ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer `ChannelPool` section at http://netty.io/news/2015/05/07/4-0-28-Final.html

Comment: Channel pool is working fine for me. The only issue which i am facing is that when server replies to client i am not able to get that in my client handler (extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> ) channelRead0 method. Any hint ?

Comment: bootstrap.handler() is overridden by ChannelPool. So the b.handler(new ClientInitializer()); will not have any effect.

Comment: @AbhishekSen how can I resolve that issue? I tried adding new ClientInitializer(); in ChannelPoolHandler when channelCreated(); but still I get issue

Comment: @JavaMachine Check this out https://gist.github.com/kumrigar/522e2556d2f119e26319 How they write the Initializer code inside channelCreated callback of ChannelPoolHandler

Comment: @AbhishekSen I guess I did the same thing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315586/how-to-use-fixedchannelpool-with-websockets this post explains everything

Comment: @AbhishekSen Thank you for your help, I found solution to my problem.

Comment: FYI . Channel pooling will be deprecated in netty 5 : https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/8681