# How to use FixedChannelPool with WebSockets?

Tags: java, websocket, netty, pool

Hello fellow developers...

I am trying to implement WebSocket fixed connection pool, unfortunately netty provided poor guide for `FixedChannelPool` and maximum "what you can get" is their [Unit Tests](https://insight.io/github.com/netty/netty/blob/HEAD/transport/src/test/java/io/netty/channel/pool/FixedChannelPoolTest.java?line=139)

Client code that I am using example [Source Code](https://github.com/spmallette/netty-example/tree/master/src/test/java/com/genoprime/netty/example)

and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748424/how-to-create-channel-pool-in-netty) found out that `bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<>())` is overridden by `ChannelPool`

Then I tried to move `ChannelInitializer` block to:

```
public class SomeConnectionPoolHandler implements ChannelPoolHandler {

    private final URI uri = URI.create("ws://some.url:80");

    @Override
    public void channelCreated(Channel ch) {
        String protocol = uri.getScheme();
        if (!"ws".equals(protocol)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported protocol: " + protocol);
        }

        DefaultHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new DefaultHttpHeaders();
        final WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker = WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, httpHeaders, 1280000);
        final WebSocketClientHandler handler = new WebSocketClientHandler(handshaker, connection);
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpClientCodec(),  new HttpObjectAggregator(65536), handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReleased(Channel ch) {
        //TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void channelAcquired(Channel ch) {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

And now my client code looks like:

```
public class Application {
    private final URI uri = URI.create("ws://some.url:80");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Channel ch = null;
        try {
            String protocol = uri.getScheme();
            if (!"ws".equals(protocol)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported protocol: " + protocol);
            }
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
            b.remoteAddress(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());

            b.group(group);
            b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
            SomeConnectionPoolHandler connectionPoolHandler = new SomeConnectionPoolHandler ();

            channelPool = new FixedChannelPool(b, connectionPoolHandler, 8);
            ch = channelPool.acquire().sync().get();
            ch.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("test")).sync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(ch != null) {
                channelPool.release(ch);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: TextWebSocketFrame (expected: ByteBuf, FileRegion)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.filterOutboundMessage(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:799)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1291)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:816)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:528)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:101)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.write(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1136)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1078)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I find solution to my problem.

The problem is that I was trying to write data to `Channel` before WebSocket Handshake is completed.

In [handler source code](https://github.com/spmallette/netty-example/blob/master/src/test/java/com/genoprime/netty/example/WebSocketClientHandler.java) you can see that it has method to get `ChannelFuture` for WebSocket Handshake.

```
public ChannelFuture handshakeFuture() {
        return handshakeFuture;
    }
```

Now, after acquiring `Channel` from `FixedChannelPool`, I am calling method (returns whether handshake was completed or not):

```
private boolean isConnectionReady(Channel ch) {
        try {
            WebSocketClientHandler handler = (WebSocketClientHandler) ch.pipeline().get("handler");
            return handler.handshakeFuture().sync().isSuccess();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Also added name for `WebSocketClientHandler` in `channelCreated(Channel ch)`

```
DefaultHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new DefaultHttpHeaders();
final WebSocketClientHandshaker handshaker = WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, httpHeaders, 1280000);
final WebSocketClientHandler handler = new WebSocketClientHandler(handshaker, connection);
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast(new HttpClientCodec(),  new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
pipeline.addLast("handler", handler);
```

I know that this code now looks awful and should be refactored.