# What is the difference between channelpool and channelgroupl

Tags: netty

What is the difference between `channelpool` and `channelgroup`? Could someone provide an example or usecase showcasing this difference?

Comment: See http://netty.io/news/2015/05/07/4-0-28-Final.html via https://stackoverflow.com/a/30748650/1531971

Answer (score 1):

A [ChannelPool](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/pool/ChannelPool.html) is a pool of "borrowable" Channels to constrain the number of connections and lower the cost of acquiring a connected Channel. Analogous to a JEE [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html).

A [ChannelGroup](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) offers lifecycle controlled state control for established Channels, normally setup so that a close event on an inserted channel will eject the channel from the group. Loosely analogous (in some cases) to a [HttpSession](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), except more generalized for various protocols/transports.

Not sure of those analogies are familiar to you.....

Answer (score 1):

To add to Nicholas' answer, their use cases are different.

A `ChannelPool` is used to implement [connection-pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) (usually) in a database or HTTP client.

A `ChannelGroup` is used to implement broadcast functionality and other bulk operations. For example, you can disconnect all channels in the group at once, or send a message to all channels in the group.